# Is there a way to watch webcam activation event?

Tags: javascript, operating-system, electron, webcam

I'm creating a background app in electron and the objective is to send a notification every time the webcam is activated.

Is there a way to catch those webcam activation events from system to trigger a function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "clean" solution in javascript.

- First you have to take the accepted answer in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592738/jquery-webcam-flash-how-to-detect-if-webcam-is-active)
- to not use jQuery you have to extract the relevant function(s) from the jQuery source
- Then you have to have permission to access the camera.
- The js doing that has either to run over https or from a local file

So the good news is its doable. Even trying that with C# or C++ directly on the OS-level is a PITA.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about keep checking if the camera is active with a timeout but I am not sure about keep "pinging" the webcam